# HTML scaled down 50 % in iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, ios, mobile-safari, frameset

We have a client site which uses below html. When I open the URL in safari browser on desktop the URL page renders correctly fitting completely. When the similar page is opened in iPhone the page shrinks to 50% height.

First i thought the issue is because of our code but when we check in iPhone the code at our end works as expected.

Below is the HTML. Requesting help on this. Thanks

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Test.com</title>
 </head>

<!-- frames -->
 <frameset>
    <frame name="test.com" src="http://www.google.com" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"    scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></frame>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Does the client's iPhone have a different pixel density than the one you tested on?

Comment: No we even checked on our iphones and still same result. What is he missing in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the default viewport of the page.

> Safari on iOS sets the size and scale of the viewport to reasonable
>   defaults that work well for most webpages. The default width is 980
>   pixels.
>   [(source)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW27)

You will need to setup your own viewport. By setting a viewport the browser recognises how the content should fit on the device's screen.

Simply adding the following meta tag to your  should fix your problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

For more options and information on configuring the viewport visit  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html